# In the template of dom-repeat that the expression doesn’t succeed

Tags: binding, polymer, expression, dom-repeat

```
 <dom-repeat id="xRepeat" as="x">
         <template is="dom-repaet">
             <div>
                 <dom-repeat  items="[[x]]" as="y">
                     <template is="dom-repaet">
                         <div>
                             <dom-repeat  items="[[y]]" as="z">
                                 <template is="dom-repaet">
                                     <span  checked-data-id="{{x*y*z}}" >
                                        {{z}}
                                     </span>
                                 </template>
                             </dom-repeat>
                         </div>
                     </template>
                 </dom-repeat>
             </div>
         </template>
     </dom-repeat>
```

"{{x*y*z}}" is no response in Polymer#2.0.

What can I do to make it work?
                        ? ? ?
                         ?
               ( @      @ )
 I'm feeling  (     <      )  ...

Comment: What is the value of x?

Comment: Wait your first dom-repeat does not have any bindings?? Why??

Comment: what would `{{x*y*z*}}` mean? do you want to multiply some values? if so, I am not sure how you're both using `x` and `y` for iterations and also as numbers.. but anyway, those bindings are not that advanced, to allow you to perform operations in them.. instead you could pass them to a method, let's say `multiply(x, y, z)` that would return your value